Stop propagation click on arrow caroussel javascript
I have a problem with a carousel. It works more or less well but I cannot stop the click event between each slide of the carousel. If I click several times on the arrows, the carousel does not work correctly. I think the click event is propagating, but stopPropation() doesn't work. I'm not sure that I'm going in the right direction.


(() => {
  const arrowPrevious = document.querySelector(".chevron__previous");
  const arrowNext = document.querySelector(".chevron__next");
  const carousselPictures = document.querySelector(".caroussel__pictures");
  const caroussel = document.querySelector(".caroussel");
  const interval = document
    .querySelector(".caroussel__pictures")
    .getAttribute("data-interval");
  const size = 1000;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    carousselPictures.style.transform = "translateX(" + -size + "px)";
    setTimeout(() => {
      carousselPictures.appendChild(carousselPictures.firstElementChild);
      carousselPictures.style = "left: 0; transition: none !important;";
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      carousselPictures.style = "left: 0;";
    }, 1020);
  };

  const previousSlide = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      carousselPictures.prepend(carousselPictures.lastElementChild);
      carousselPictures.style =
        "left: " + -size + "px !important; transition: none !important;";
    }, 1);

    setTimeout(() => {
      carousselPictures.style.transform = "translateX(" + -size + "px)";
      carousselPictures.style = "transition: all 1s ease-out !important;";
    }, 2);
  };

  arrowPrevious.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    previousSlide();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  arrowNext.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    nextSlide();
  });

  let timer = setInterval((e) => {
    nextSlide();
  }, parseInt(interval) + 40);

  caroussel.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  });

  caroussel.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      nextSlide();
    }, parseInt(interval) + 40);
  });
})();

// slider();
@import url(reset.css);
html,
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title__h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.25rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.caroussel,
.caroussel__pictures {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out !important;
}

.picture {
  position: relative;
}

.caroussel {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.caroussel__pictures {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

.transition__toggle {
  transition: none !important;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  top: calc(50% - (48px / 2));
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.chevron__previous,
.chevron__next {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title__h1">Caroussel javascript</h1>

  <div class="caroussel">
    <div class="caroussel__pictures" data-interval="2000">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/1000/400" alt="image caroussel 1" class="picture" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/11//1000/400" alt="image caroussel 2" class="picture" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12//1000/400" alt="image caroussel 3" class="picture" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/13//1000/400" alt="image caroussel 4" class="picture" />
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left chevron__previous"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right chevron__next"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




my answer was pretty rushed and didn't take into account newer details coming from the edited question. I preferred to delete it to leave space for better answers to come in

btw I had doubts about your approach. How did you expect the carousel to be reset when the 4th slide is reached? There are 2 main approaches: scrolling the whole strip back to the first slide and restart the loop; or just gives the illusion of an infinite scroll where the 1st follows the 4th. I ask because I saw the main problem of the "glitch" you are trying to address to be that specific behviour. Plus you may fix the next slide  action made by the setInterval by passing the nextSlide function as is without wrapping its invocation in a new function like setInterval(nextSlide, delay)

Also, for starters, the use of stopPropation() and stopImmediatePropagation() - for no actual reason - should be avoided.

The best way to avoid overlapping movement requests is to prohibit any action while a slide movement is in action.
To do this, you need to use a listener indicating the end of Transition. => this is transitionend event.
caroussel.addEventListener('transitionend', e => ...

Be careful, each move generate this event.
The other part of this solution concerns the CSS, in order to ignore any click during a move:
caroussel.into_mov_action > .arrowButton {
  pointer-events : none;
  ...

I simplified your code a bit in order to show these uses:


(() =>  // slider IIFE code   
  {
  const
    movPrev        = document.querySelector('.fa-chevron-left')
  , movNext        = document.querySelector('.fa-chevron-right')
  , caroussel      = document.querySelector('.caroussel')
  , interval_40    = 40 + Number( caroussel.dataset.interval )
  , size           = caroussel.offsetWidth
  , caroussel_imgs = caroussel.querySelectorAll('.caroussel > img')  
  , movVars        = { top: 0, next:0, len: caroussel_imgs.length, endTransCount: 0, timer:0 }
    ;
  const nextSlide = () =>
    {
    if (caroussel.classList.contains('onMov')) return; // == exit => avoid overlapping movement requests

    caroussel.classList.add('onMov'); // to indicate that an animation is in progress
    movVars.endTransCount = 2; // and that it will generate 2 "transitionend" events

    movVars.next = (movVars.top + 1) % movVars.len;

    caroussel_imgs[movVars.next].classList.add('next');
    caroussel_imgs[movVars.top].classList.add('movLeftOut');
    }
  const prevSlide = () =>
    {
    if (caroussel.classList.contains('onMov')) return;

    caroussel.classList.add('onMov');
    movVars.endTransCount = 2;

    movVars.next = (movVars.top - 1 + movVars.len)  % movVars.len;

    caroussel_imgs[movVars.next].classList.add('next');
    caroussel_imgs[movVars.top].classList.add('movRightOut');
    }
  caroussel.addEventListener('transitionend', e =>
    {
    if (!caroussel.classList.contains('onMov') ) return;
    movVars.endTransCount--;

    if ( movVars.endTransCount === 1) // after 1st mov to show new img
      {
      caroussel_imgs[movVars.next].classList.replace('next','top');
      caroussel_imgs[movVars.top].classList.remove('top', 'movLeftOut', 'movRightOut');
      }
    if ( movVars.endTransCount === 0) // after second mov to restore moved/hidden element to position=0
      {
      movVars.top = movVars.next;
      caroussel.classList.remove('onMov'); // indicate ready to move action!
      }
    })

  movPrev.addEventListener('click', prevSlide );
  movNext.addEventListener('click', nextSlide );

  movVars.timer = setInterval( nextSlide, interval_40);

  caroussel.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => { clearInterval(movVars.timer) });
  caroussel.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => { movVars.timer = setInterval( nextSlide, interval_40) });

  })();
*,html,body {
  margin      : 0;
  border      : 0;
  box-sizing  : border-box;
  }
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
.caroussel {
  --wSize     : 1000px;
  --hSize     : 400px;
  width       : var(--wSize);
  height      : var(--hSize);
  margin      : 2rem auto 0 auto;
  position    : relative;
  overflow    : hidden;
  }
.caroussel > img {
  position    : absolute;
  top         : 0;
  left        : 0;
  width       : var(--wSize);
  height      : var(--hSize);
  transition  : all 1s ease-in-out;
  }
.caroussel > img.top  { z-index  : 220; }
.caroussel > img.next { z-index  : 210; }
.caroussel > img:not(.top, .next)  { display : none; }

.caroussel > img.movLeftOut  { transform: translateX( var(--wSize)  ); }
.caroussel > img.movRightOut { transform: translateX(  calc(var(--wSize) * -1 ) );  }

.arrows {
  position        : absolute;
  top             : calc( (var(--hSize) / 2) - 1.5rem);
  left            : 0;
  width           : 100%;
  padding         : 0 2rem;
  z-index         : 300;
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
  color           : #ffffff62;
  }
.caroussel:not(.onMov):hover .arrows {
  color           : white;
  }  
.arrows > .fa-solid {
  font-size  : 3rem;
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
.caroussel.onMov .fa-solid:hover {
  pointer-events : none;
  cursor         : default;
  }  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css">

<div class="caroussel" data-interval="3000">  <!-- onMov -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/1000/400" alt="image caroussel 1" class="top">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/1000/400" alt="image caroussel 2" class="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/1000/400" alt="image caroussel 3" class="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/13/1000/400" alt="image caroussel 4" class="">
  <div class="arrows">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left "></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>



